# c# Mobile phone number masking

Tags: c#

I want to mask the middle of the phone number

Since a phone number can have 3 to 12 digits, I think you need to calculate the number of digits and process it.

In java procedure, it is handled like this

```
WHEN LENGTH(phoneNmmber) < 3 THEN phoneNmmber  
WHEN LENGTH(phoneNmmber) < 7 THEN RPAD(SUBSTR(phoneNmmber,1,3), LENGTH(phoneNmmber), '*')  
ELSE CONCAT(LEFT(phoneNmmber, 3), RPAD('', LENGTH(phoneNmmber) - 7, '*'), RIGHT(phoneNmmber, 4))
```

I want to convert it in a different way. I want to convert a query written in mysql to an mssql query. Can you do the same?

Comment: If you can show us the code in C# then we can check it for you.

Comment: It appears that your "Java procedure" is actually an SQL query. Can't you just perform the same query from C#? Or do you mean you have a `string` within C# itself that you need to perform a similar operation on? If so, have you checked the [documentation for `string`'s methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0#methods)?

Comment: I've added the code. If you can help, I'd like to help

Comment: Don't ever parse a phone number to a numeric type. Although they have *digits*, they're still text. Zeroes are significant, and especially when you're pulling out a substring, you can have leading zeroes that will be lost by parsing. Your SQL expression doesn't do it. Don't do it in C#, either.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question The sql in question is written in mysql. What should I do if I convert it to mssql?

Comment: Telephone numbers aren't numbers.

Comment: I want to convert it in a different way. I want to convert a query written in mysql to an mssql query. Can you do the same?

Comment: `RPAD('a', 4, '*')` would result in `a***`. The equivalent in MSSQL would be `LEFT('a' + '****', 4)`. `SUBSTR` would become `SUBSTRING`, `LENGTH` -> `LEN`. I think that's the only changes you need to make?

Comment: I was writing an answer, but the question is now closed. Please see here: https://pastebin.com/KqbrS8a1

Comment: @codeman I get [identical results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1unG.png) from both queries. If something is wrong, then it's also wrong in the original query.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a 'java procedure' and definitely not Java code. This is an SQL statement. If you are using the same database with your C# program, you should be able to use the same code. Otherwise, use these hints to convert your SQL code to C# code:

```
WHEN THEN statement --> if () else () ....
LENGTH --> String.Length
RPAD --> String.PadRight()
CONCAT --> String.Concat()
SUBSTRING --> String.Substring()
LEFT --> String.Substring()
RIGHT --> String.Substring(String.Length - X)
```